# Firefox Hebrew characters

Tags: firefox, hebrew

I have this string: "¿Employer עִבְרִית #"
In Firefox 35.0.1 span block it not registered to the end of string.

```
<div>
    <span>¿Employer עִבְרִית #</span>
</div>
```

Please, inspect elements [here](http://jsfiddle.net/son3zwa5/) and select span and you can see that span selection is ending after "Employer" not at the end of the sting.

Does anyone see the solution for this?

Comment: Did you try on jsfiddle example?

Comment: Yes, and as expected the span contains the entire string, not stopping after "employer"

Comment: This is how I see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mu44dwg4xilbijg/Screenshot%20from%202015-01-26%2019%3A49%3A01.png?dl=0

Comment: probably just a visual bug. note that the parsed tree shows the entire text inside the span. report it to the FF devs.

Comment: I will report it to FF devs for sure. One more thing, take a look and tell me where do you see red square? http://jsfiddle.net/son3zwa5/1/

Comment: It's a Firefox bug. Report to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/